# How to get the offset of daylight saving time if applicable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a site launched in a server located in a zone where daylight saving changes are applicable. I store certain dates as local time in the database. When I pull these dates back to plot in a Fullcalendar (jQuery), it changes the time automatically to the browser's time zone. I have the logic in server side to show the date properly in the calendar. But, when the daylight saving changes are applicable, the time in the calendar shows a difference of an hour.
I want the offset of this saving in code, so that I could put some logic to ignore or override this kind of time.

Comment: Probably better to save dates in your DB in UTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution:

```
var returnDate = System.DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
var tRules = TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetAdjustmentRules().ToList();
var rule = tRules.OrderBy(x => x.DateEnd).FirstOrDefault();
var timeSpan = rule.DaylightDelta;
if (timeSpan != null)
{
    returnDate = returnDate + timeSpan;
}
```

If daylight saving changes are allowed in the datetime settings, then the AdjustmentRules would be returned, other wise empty.

So the timespan is the hour & minutes to be attached to the required datetime value.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the daylight-delta, you might want to contrast it with this:

```
    TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTimeOffset.Now)
```

Keeping in mind the following "Note":

> The GetUtcOffset method recognizes only the current daylight saving time adjustment rule for the local time zone. As a result, it is guaranteed to accurately return the UTC offset of a local time only during the period in which the latest adjustment rule is in effect. It may return inaccurate results if time is a historic date and time value that was subject to a previous adjustment rule.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezone.getutcoffset?view=net-5.0